# Carbon вывести дату в секундах

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

подскажите, как вывести дату 2020-12-02 в секундах через Carbon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос

```
Carbon::now()->timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Carbon::parse('2020-12-02')->getTimestamp()
```

вернет 1606867200, что равно 2020-12-02 00:00:00